# Vertica: convert integer result to a specific format (eg. from 6.50945378E8 to 650,945,378)

Tags: sql, vertica

This is my query:

```
select send_date
        , sum(total_requests) as 'All'
        , sum(portion_requests) as 'Subset'
        , (sum(total_requests)-sum(portion_requests)) as 'Delta'
from f_stats
where send_date = '2015-01-22'
group by send_date
```

The "total_requests" and "portion_requests" elements are numbers.  The sum of these numbers is in the hundreds of millions (eg 500,000,000).  My query results are returned in an undesired format.  They look like "6.50945378E8" when I want them to look like "650,945,378".

How do I force the formatting?

Answer (score 3):

To put commas in a number, you need to convert it to a string.  You should be able to do this with the `to_char()` function.  Something like:

```
select to_char(sum(total_requests), '999,999,999,999') as total_requests
```